# Execute and stop shell command with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, command

I want to start a script (with arguments and in another process) using NodeJS code but I want to be able to stop it later on.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this : `ctrl + c` and press `Y` (if console ask `Y/N`)